# .htaccess rules to rewrite https and restirct some urls to certian IPs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two .htaccess rules one to rewrite https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and another to restrict some urls to only be accessible from whitelisted IPs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^111.123.456.222
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

the second rule works fine by itself but when I add the first both i get the too many redirects error how do i get the first rule to work (on some servers it works properly)?

**UPDATE**
I am closing this question until I hear from my host if there is something in my server environment that is causing my problem

Answer (score 2):

Ok i confirmed with my hosting service, my problem was i had pound sitting in front of my server (for varnish) :-) .  I switched it to haproxy and that is redirecting all my traffic to HTTPS so I don't need anything in the .htaccesss, Thank you